# Fetch the latest information in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a below table in MySQL DB.

```
create table shops(
        id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        shopid bigint(10) NOT NULL,
        first_level_shop_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        start_time datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        rate int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        KEY shopid (shopid,first_level_shop_id,start_time)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would like to fetch the rate of shop's all latest first_level_shop_id(need to consider start_time).
The one shopid is having many first_level_shop_id.
for example:

```
shopid,first_level_shop_id,rate,start_time
110,110001,20,2018-08-16 00:00:00
110,210011,50,2018-08-16 00:00:00
```

There are many first_level_shop_id under one shopid 110.I would like to fetch the latest one.
Please help me to write the SELECT query for the same.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from shops s
where s.start_time = (select max(s2.start_time)
                      from shops s2
                      where s2.shopid = s.shopid
                     );
```